# Getting Python code for ArcToolbox call

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arctoolbox

Is it possible to get the exact Python code corresponding to a specific run of a tool in ArcToolbox?

The reason I ask is that I want to replicate the function in a Tool in Python, and adapt it to my needs.

I have tried some md tool for ncdf, which works in the GUI but not in python if I write the Python code by hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After running the tool navigate to the 'Results' window (which can be found under the Geoprocessing menu), right click on the process and select "Copy As Python Snippet".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use ModelBuilder to configure your algorithm, drag & drop the tools that you need from the toolbox. Configure the inputs and outputs, and then in the ModelBuilder window export to Python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tools can be added to ModelBuilder and exported as Python code. It is a technique I have often used to replicate tools in Python.