# Correct syntax for search query restrictions in arcpy.CalculateLocations_na?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst

In ArcMap, I have created a tool using Model Builder that has a Calculate Locations (Network Analyst) step. This step includes a Search Query to restrict Routing_Streets to features that are not CONTROLLED_ACCESS and not FERRY. It works perfectly when I run it from the model, but not when I export it to python script and run it in IDLE.

This is the script that the Model Builder exports:

```
arcpy.CalculateLocations_na(MyInputFeaturesFC, Routing_ND, "100 Feet", "Routing_Streets SHAPE;Routing_Streets_Override NONE;Routing_ND_Junctions NONE", "PRIORITY", "SourceID", "SourceOID", "PosAlong", "SideOfEdge", "SnapX", "SnapY", "Distance", "", "", "INCLUDE", "Routing_Streets 'CONTROLLED_ACCESS ='N' AND FERRY='N'';Routing_Streets_Override #;Routing_ND_Junctions #")
```

In IDLE the Check Module finds no problems, but when I Run Module I get this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\na.py", line 468, in CalculateLocations
raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

After trial and error, I have determined that the error goes away if I remove the `'CONTROLLED_ACCESS ='N' AND FERRY='N''` and replace it with `#`, therefore I believe that the syntax is incorrect, but I've tried all different combinations of quotes, escaping quotes, and other syntax that I can think of.

Comment: Can you run the CalculateLocations GP tool directly and then right click on the result and select 'Copy as Python Snippet' to get the syntax you need. E.g. similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139234/how-to-get-the-python-code-for-a-arctoolbox-call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the 'Copy as Python Snippet' created essentially the same script as the Model Builder's export it to python script, other than it included the parameter names (e.g., search_query=), therefore I got the same error.  It may or may not be due to the syntax of the search query, but I have tested multiple times and every time I include a search query string, it produces that error.

Comment: Maybe try a very simple query, not sure what is allowed but maybe something like objectid > 0 .

Comment: And maybe try `'"CONTROLLED_ACCESS" = 'N' AND "FERRY" = 'N''`, so adding double quotes around the field names.

Comment: Thanks again @darkfader for the ideas. Your idea of testing a search query with a numeric condition proved to work. I tried: ```'"SPEED_CLASS"=14'``` and it worked perfectly. However I still cannot determine the correct syntax to get a string condition to work in the search query.  (BTW '"CONTROLLED_ACCESS" = 'N' AND "FERRY" = 'N'' did not work.)

Comment: (BTW ```'"CONTROLLED_ACCESS" = 'N' AND "FERRY" = 'N''``` did not work. It resulted in a syntax error, with the N highlighted)

Comment: The solution turned out to be to utilize string variable substitution while escaping the single quotes around the 'N's in a simple string (escaping the single quotes inline inside the arcpy.CalculateLocations_na was causing the error)

Comment: Here's the final, functioning code:  `routingStreetsSelect = ' "CONTROLLED_ACCESS" = \'N\' And FERRY = \'N\' '`  
  `searchquery = [["Routing_Streets", routingStreetsSelect],["Routing_Streets_Override",""],["Routing_ND_Junctions",""]]`   
  `arcpy.CalculateLocations_na(Uniti_Structures_fc, Routing_ND__2_, "100 Feet", "Routing_Streets SHAPE;Routing_Streets_Override NONE;Routing_ND_Junctions NONE", "PRIORITY", "SourceID", "SourceOID", "PosAlong", "SideOfEdge", "SnapX", "SnapY", "Distance", "", "", "INCLUDE", searchquery)`